# (x)Ubuntu 19.10 wifi stops and never restarts until next reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, xubuntu, 19.10

**Problem**
When I reboot my computer, wifi is either off or on. When it's on, if it goes off, it stays off forever until next reboot. When it's off, it stays off. I need wifi to stay on, or to be able to restart it when it's off, without rebooting my computer.

**What I tried**
- I tried standard network restart commands (ifconfig wlp10s0 down/up, service network-manager restart, rfkill unblock wifi, nmcli netwoking off/on)
- I tried booting on an USB stick (same xubuntu 19.10), wifi on the usb stick works perfectly fine for a long time, which seems to exclude everything but a software/firmware problem.

**Error message**
- The only source of information I have is when typing dmesg:
" wlp10s0 *(that's my interface)*: send auth to [some hex address with 12 characters?] (try 1/3)
etc.., with 2/3, 3/3 and then "authentication with [same hex address] timed out"

**How did it happened**
- I tried to install docker-ce but it seems to have broken my wifi (I didn't only install docker), after uninstalling it, it didn't change. I also tried make on rtlwifi_new, which solved an initial problem (with rtl8192ee which is my network controller in lspci) but this problem still remains.
- Another error in dmesg is "rtl8192ee, AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x...]"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can look at the logs with the command `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out I misread the instructions on rtlwifi_new github repository here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/blob/extended/README.md

It clearly said : "rtl8192ce, rtl8192cu, rtl8192se, rtl8192de, rtl8188ee, **rtl8192ee**, rtl8723ae, rtl8723be, rtl8821ae, and rtl8723de. The rtl8723de is available **ONLY** in the extended branch, which is the recommended one."
But I used the master branch instead.

After reinstalling the right driver and rebooting, it went well. I had greyed out option when I wanted to modify my wifi settings but I used "sudo nm-connection-editor", added my WPA key and the wifi worked. Now I can disable and re-enable my wifi without any trouble.

It only tooks me 6h to solve everything so, yeah, ubuntu and wifi drivers will always be win.